# Spring boot application-test.properties not initializes inside the tested component

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, application.properties

I'm writing a test for a component that takes values from the application.properties.

In the test itself the values are picked up correctly from the application-test.properies. 
I used @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")

However in the tested class the values are NOT getting picked up and are null.

The test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class ArtifactAssociationHandlerTest {

private InputStream inputStreamMock;
private ArtifactEntity artifactMock;
private ArtifactDeliveriesRequestDto requestDto;
@Value("${sdc.be.endpoint}")
private String sdcBeEndpoint;
@Value("${sdc.be.protocol}")
private String sdcBeProtocol;
@Value("${sdc.be.external.user}")
private String sdcUser;
@Value("${sdc.be.external.password}")
private String sdcPassword;

@Mock
private RestTemplate restClientMock;

@Mock
private RestTemplateBuilder builder;

@InjectMocks
private ArtifactAssociationService associationService;

@Before
public void setUp() throws IOException {
    inputStreamMock = IOUtils.toInputStream("some test data for my input stream", "UTF-8");
    artifactMock = new ArtifactEntity(FILE_NAME, inputStreamMock);
    requestDto = new ArtifactDeliveriesRequestDto("POST",END_POINT);
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    associationService = Mockito.spy(new ArtifactAssociationService(builder));
    associationService.setRestClient(restClientMock);
}
```

The Tested component:

```
@Component("ArtifactAssociationHandler")
public class ArtifactAssociationService {

@Value("${sdc.be.endpoint}")
private String sdcBeEndpoint;
@Value("${sdc.be.protocol}")
private String sdcBeProtocol;
@Value("${sdc.be.external.user}")
private String sdcUser;
@Value("${sdc.be.external.password}")
private String sdcPassword;

private RestTemplate restClient;

@Autowired
public ArtifactAssociationService(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    this.restClient = builder.build();
}

 void setRestClient(RestTemplate restClient){
    this.restClient = restClient;
}
```

How can I properly test this with application-test.properties?

Answer (score 1):

Your `setup` method is creating the instance of `ArtifactAssociationService`. This means that it isn't a Spring bean and, therefore, doesn't have any dependency injection performed. This includes injection into fields annotated with `@Value`.

If you want the `@Value`-annotated fields to have their values injected, you will have to make your `ArtifactAssociationService` instance a bean, for example by creating it using a `@Bean` method in a `@Configuration` class.

Comment: I originally didn't create the instance in the setup method, it was on order to set the restCilent to the mock instance.
Even after removing the initialization - it's still the same (values are null) :

    @Spy
   InjectMocks
    private ArtifactAssociationService associationService;

    Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        //associationService = Mockito.spy(new ArtifactAssociationService(builder));
        associationService.setRestClient(restClientMock);
    }

Comment: It's hard to read code in a comment, but it looks like you're still creating the `ArtifactAssociationService` yourself: `new ArtifactAssociationService(builder)`.

Comment: sorry, I couldn't add it as code block.. this line is commented out